# Mysqldump crashes mysql with out of memory error

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I am trying to run mysqldump to dump mysql for another replica.
I am running the following command

```
mysqldump --quick --all-databases --master-data | gzip > dump.sql.gz
```

But when I run it, I get mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping table `email_outgoing_event` at row: 641 error.
At first, I thought that changing mysql system variables might help,so I changed
max_allowed_packet and net_write_timeout to their maximum values. But this did not help.
Then, while running the mysqldump, I also ran top to see memory usage. And I saw that mysqld process reaches around 95%+ of memory usage and then crashes.
In syslog I found this

```
Jan  3 12:54:32 SQL-01 kernel: [70597184.992464] Out of memory: Kill process 7259 (mysqld) score 954 or sacrifice child
Jan  3 12:54:32 SQL-01 kernel: [70597185.100722] Killed process 7259 (mysqld) total-vm:15365328kB, anon-rss:13685060kB, file-rss:0kB
Jan  3 12:54:33 SQL-01 mysqld_safe[6590]: 230103 12:54:33 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
Jan  3 12:54:33 SQL-01 CRON[7523]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jan  3 12:54:33 SQL-01 mysqld_safe[6590]: 230103 12:54:33 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
```

What solution can I use? Is there a way to restrict mysql to use certain amount of memory so that Out Of Memory is avoided?

Also, the database I am trying to dump is quite big - running du -sh command on mysql data dir shows 133G.

Comment: *Out of memory: Kill process*, means that the Linux system is critically low on memory. What is the amount of free storage on your system ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha , we have 70G availabe(checked with df -h) on disk and 14GB ram total(checked with /proc/meminfo).

Comment: TERMINOLOGY -- "Memory" == "RAM"; "Disk space" is a different thing.